# Laravel 5.0 Error exception with message Undefined property

Tags: php, sql, pdo, laravel-5

I'm having some problems with some SQL in Laravel in a controller.

Here's what i have :

```
public function getKeyword()
{
    $date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
    echo ($date);


    $keyword = DB::table('demo_question_keyword')
                ->select('keyword')
                ->orderBy('date_from', 'desc')
                ->having('date_from', '>=', $date)
                ->limit(1)
                ->get();

    echo ($keyword);
}
```

This prints the date correctly, but it seems like `$keyword` does not retrieve what i want correctly. 
I also tried to make it more simple, using `$keyword = DB::select('select keyword from demo_question_keyword');` but i'm getting the same error.

I also tried with PDO in a different way (login hidden for privacy, my login isn't in fault anyway i'm correctly logged in my database without problems) :

```
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $bdd = new PDO('localhost::3306;dbname=****', '*******', '*******', $pdo_options);

    $stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT keyword FROM demo_question_keyword ORDER BY id_question DESC LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch;

    echo $row['keyword'];
```

but again, same error.

This is the error i'm always getting :

```
local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined property: stdClass::$exactLocation'
```

And this is the line that the error is directing to :

```
$campaign->exact_location = $jsonBody->exactLocation;
```

But it seems weird to me because `$exactLocation` has nothing to do with what i'm doing in my controller.
Also, i only have one line in my table so there is not more than one retrived results i would say.

Thank you for taking the time to try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d");

$keyword = DB::table('demo_question_keyword')
            ->select('keyword')
            ->orderBy('date_from', 'desc')
            ->having('date_from', '>=', $date)
            ->limit(1)
            ->toSql();
dd($keyword)
```

If query display with right result and the problem is $exactLocation is undefined, so where you put $exactLocation

Comment: I'm not putting $exactLocation anywhere in my controller, that's what confuses me. This var is from another controller that isn't linked with this one at all.

Comment: was trying composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: Why do you want me to do that ?

Comment: that autoloader, if you create class with manually not with command line, in laravel you must generate it, so your apps know your new class..

Comment: I did it, i could not access anything in my localhost after so i removes the autoload files in vendor/composer and i ran composer install